# setting a route for magento new module

Tags: magento

i have registered a new module

```
 cd /path/to/store/app
 touch etc/modules/Maticode_WebLog.xml

  <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
   <modules>
    <Maticode_WebLog>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Maticode_WebLog>
   </modules>
 </config>
```

add this config file:

```
  touch app/code/local/Maticode/WebLog/etc/config.xml

 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
<modules>
    <Maticode_WebLog>
        <version>
            0.1.0
        </version>
    </Maticode_WebLog>
</modules>


<frontend>
    <routers>           
        <weblog>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Maticode_WebLog</module>
                <frontName>weblog</frontName>
            </args>
        </weblog>
    </routers>
</frontend>

   </config>
```

clear the cache  (backoffice:system/cache management:disable all),

add a controller to it

```
   touch app/code/local/Maticode/WebLog/controllers/IndexController.php

     <?php 


class Maticode_WebLog_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {    

public function indexAction(){
    echo "indexaction";
  //        $this->loadLayout();
  //        $this->renderLayout();
}

public function testModelAction() {
    echo 'Setup!';
}
```

}

this url :

```
      http://localhost/magento/weblog
       or http://localhost/magento/index.php/weblog/
```

returns 404 error , why??

Answer (score 0):

my Maticode_WebLog.xml was wrong.
This is the correct one:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Maticode_WebLog>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Maticode_WebLog>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: what are problem??explain

Comment: The codePool was not defined so the module files located in app/code/local could not be found